# WebStorm support for ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, webstorm

I'm using latest WebStorm 8.0.4 for Sencha ExtJs support. Overall, I think it is a very powerful tool that understand a lot of ExtJS specific stuff, but there is one issue which I hope somebody has a solution for that.

The problem I have is related to 'this' keyword. When I type 'this.', WebStorm is smart enough to show not only all members of the class, it also suggest the list of getter and setters for those config properties that is specific to ExtJs. but after I choose a setter, ExtJs does not understand its own suggestion and show 'unresolved function or method' under the getter and I can't navigate from this getter to the config property. Even more strange, if I do  'var me = this' then  use 'me.getSomeThing()', ExtJs has no problem.

I would appreciate any idea or suggestion on this issue.

Comment: please provide the code snippet (self-containing) that shows up the issue

Answer (score 0):

From jetbrains site:

> To enable the use of ext js in your project, perform these general
>   steps:
>
> - Download the Ext JS.
> - Configure it as a custom WebStorm
>     JavaScript library.
> - Associate the library with the project.

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-ext-js-framework.html